# Why does it displays a kernel error message whenever I try GPU rendering in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

Whenever I select GPU rendering it displays an error message. I have a Radeon RX Vega 8 GPU but still it doesn't get to work. I tried selecting only GPU rendering in Preferences tab but still it doesn't work in Blender.
The Error shows like this:  Split kernel error: failed to load kernel_path_init.
This happens every time I select GPU rendering.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/221683/cycles-opencl-and-mesa-driver-support/221710#221710

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with the Radeon RX cards if I understand this bug report correctly, updating the card drivers can help in some but not all cases as far as I've read:

https://developer.blender.org/T83130

Comment: There isn't any update available to my card driver recently but still I hope this error gets fixed soon.
Thanks for the information.

Comment: Well, some comments there also say that the driver update didn't help them, so I keep my fingers crossed for you this will be fixed soon.