# Blender OpenCL uses all of my RAM, and my VRAM, and makes my computer crash

Tags: cycles-render-engine, opencl

I have this weird thing with OpenCL/Cycles, it uses 5 GB of my ram + half my VRAM (4 gb) and the scene i am rendering isnt even complex, it is just a rigid body simulation. How do i fix this or why is blender doing this? Sorry if i made title too long or i couldn't explain correctly.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/221683/cycles-opencl-and-mesa-driver-support/221710#221710

Comment: thank you for comment