# Missing object when rendering using OPENCL GPU and CPU render

Tags: gpu, opencl

I'm new in Blender, so I tried to make an animation following youtube tutorial.

I have problem when using OpenCL for rendering

[image]

Some object is missing and the physics on the object is not working. It should be like this (using CPU only/None):

[image: using CPU only]

but the result is like this:

[image: using OpenCL GPU+CPU]

There is only one cube appear and not falling.

what should i do?

thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/221683/cycles-opencl-and-mesa-driver-support/221710

Comment: thanks for your answer