# OpenCL No compatible GPUs found for path tracing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have a radeon rx 580 GPU I had been able to render with the GPU with it. Both 2.8 and 2.9 versions used to work. I've been doing other art so I haven't rendered anything lately and tried today.

Radeon software and windows are both fully updated and I installed blender 2.93.5 today. I've also tried the 2.93.5 LTS version on Steam, 2.81 and 2.79 I know those last 2 used to work.

I started up a game and it is using my GPU according to task manager. Also a small amount here in chrome.

As a work around I rendered the thing I was trying to do today in Eevee however that's not going to be an option for everything. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

The following are all the stats / driver info for my build.

- Edition: Windows 10 Home
- Version: 21H1
- Installed on: ‎21-‎02-‎12
- OS build: 19043.1288
- Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0
- Processor: AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor 4.00 GHz
- Installed RAM: 32.0 GB
- System type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
- Pen and touch: Pen support
- GPU: Radeon RX 580
- Series - Primary/Discrete VRAM 8192 MB - GDDR5 2000 MHz
- Graphics Card Manufacturer: Powered by AMD Graphics
- Chipset: Radeon RX 580
- Series Bus Type: PCI Express 3.0
- Current Bus Settings: PCI Express 2.0 x16
- Usable Memory Size: 8192 MB
- Memory Type: GDDR5
- Memory Clock: 2000 MHz
- Core Clock: 1366 MHz
- Total Memory Bandwidth: 256 GByte/s
- Memory Bit Rate: 8.00 Gbps
- OpenGL® API Version: 4.6
- OpenCL™ API Version: 2.0

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/221683/cycles-opencl-and-mesa-driver-support

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Aww damn really? I actually bought this card because it was the best my MB could take advantage of. Thanks for the response. I guess I'll be using Eevee for a while. It works good enough for most things I've been doing lately anyway.